# `@HostListener` of `e: TouchEvent` causes Firefox to crash with "ReferenceError: TouchEvent is not defined."

Tags: angular, firefox, touch-event

Using `@HostListener` with the event parameter explicitly typed as a `TouchEvent`, causes Firefox to crash with the following error message:

> ReferenceError: TouchEvent is not defined.

An example:

```
@HostListener('touchstart', ['$event']) // or 'touchend', 'touchmove'
onTouchStart(e: TouchEvent): void {}
```

I could come up with a few ways to prevent this myself:

- use `e: TouchEvent | any` or `e: any` (or don't specify a type at all)
- use `elRef.nativeElement.addEventListener('touchstart', (e: TouchEvent) => {})`
- use `Observable.fromEvent(elRef.nativeElement, 'touchstart').subscribe((e: TouchEvent) => {})`

But using `any` or `| any` seems like a hack, and the other two options don't take advantage of the framework. **Is there another, better and safer way to deal with this issue, and if not, which option is preferable?**

(Maybe someone can also explain what Angular is actually doing and why this error only happens when the event is explicitly typed as a `TouchEvent`...)

---

EDIT: The issue is still present in Angular 7.
EDIT: <strike>This issue has apparently been fixed in Angular 6.</strike>

Comment: Do you have a reference for this? Angular Core 6.1.10 throws still this error (using with Ionic..)

Comment: No, sorry. I assumed it was fixed because it worked after updating my app from Angular 5 to 6.

Comment: It doesn't work with Angular 7. So it's still an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When there is decorator on a method, typescript compiler stores types of parameters in the metadata, which fails in desktop Firefox because TouchEvent is not defined there. It can be solved by polyfilling the missing types with stubs. Just add the following code to `polyfills.ts`

```
for (const type of ['TouchEvent']) {
    if (typeof window[type] === 'undefined') {
        window[type] = function () { };
    }
}
```

To polyfill other types, add them to the list. A word of warning - this may break code that checks for existence of touch events by detecting `window.TouchEvent`.

Anyway, the problem only seems to happen with the JIT compiler, so it will probably disappear with Ivy.

Answer (score 0):

You can tell Angular not to emit decorator metadata in tsconfig.json:
`"emitDecoratorMetadata": false`